# Pipelined Primary Cache

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

Hello what does the term **pipelined primary cache** mean and how can it be useful to reduce hit time ? I have googled the term and have not found so much about it ( not even the textbook). My teacher said that the **pipelined primary cache** limits usefulness since every acces takes 2 cycles anyway to reduce hit time.

regards,

John

Comment: Pipelining in general isn't supposed to reduce latency, but to increase throughput.

Comment: So by reading your answer I can conclude that although pipelining is used, that wont really reduce the hit time since every memory access is 2 cycles ? Could someone correct this or add more information I would be glad if someone posted something about this topic ?